TV series about an Australian fashion designer
My girlfriend keeps asking me to find out the title of her favorite childhood TV series. I had no success googling it, so I try my luck here.
What she can remember, is not much:
It was a family drama, she watched it in the late 90s, and it was about a fashion designer who lived somewhere on the coasts of Australia. The main character was a blond haired woman in her 30s raising two orphan children and living at a huge coast house with many other people (children, adults as well). She designed clothes for a living and she had no husband that’s for sure, but can’t remember if she had any partners. It's not clear if she was Australian, or just living in Australia.
Another main character was a surf store owner guy.
Any ideas about the title of this TV series?

It was a  family drama, I updated the question.

Except for Austalia and the year, this pretty much sounds like Summerland with Lori Loughlin (orphaned kids move into blonde fashion designer aunt's beach house).

That's it! Thank you. Memories fade. Answer the question if you'd like to and I will accept it.

No problem. :) Coming right up.

Summerland with Lori Loughlin (who also co-created it) ran for two seasons on the WB in 2004-2005. From IMDb:

Bradin, Nikki and Derrick are 3 kids from an average normal Kansas household. Their whole life is thrown upside-down when their parents are tragically killed in a car accident. Ava Gregory (their aunt) gets custody of her niece and nephews and they move into her Californian [beach] home (in Summerland). Ava, a struggling clothes designer, lives with her best friend and business partner, Susannah Rexford, her friend, an ex- pro surfer [with a surf shop], Jay Robertson and her ex-boyfriend, real estate agent, Johnny Durrant. All four of them are highly unequipped to handle children and are not use to including them in their everyday lives.

Surf-pro Jay was Australian, so maybe that confused you.

